# Duplicate questions show up as "on hold" and "closed" in recently deleted questions

Tags: bug, status-completed, duplicate-questions, deleted-questions, recently-deleted

In my recently deleted questions, those that have been marked as duplicates show up as "[on hold]" or "[closed]", which should show up as "[duplicate]". Examples:

- A question that was marked as a duplicate less than 5 days ago and later deleted will show up as "[on hold]" in the recently deleted list:
  [image: on hold duplicate]
- A question that was marked as a duplicate more than 5 days ago and later deleted will show up as "[closed]" in the recently deleted question list:
  [image: closed duplicate]
- However, when you click on such a question and view it, the "[duplicate]" indicator shows up properly:
  [image: duplicate duplicate]

Is this by design, or is it a bug?

Comment: I don't really see why it would be particularly important to distinguish the two from that view.  On the /questions page, when looking for a question/answer whether it's a dup or not is often enough quite relevant.  I don't see why it would be important to distinguish the two on that page though; you're generally not going there to look for an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will be fixed in the next deploy.

That page just wasn't querying for the "duplicate"-y-ness of questions.