# Don't hide the "closed", "duplicate", or "migrated" state of questions on user question lists

Tags: bug, status-completed, profile-page, moderator-tools, closed-questions

The redesign of the activity page of the user profile broke a lot of workflows for moderators. One important purpose of that page was to gain a quick overview about what kind of posts a particular user has been posting, especially whether they have low scores or are closed often.

The new activity page makes this impossible. The view is not compact enough to quickly scan questions, which is a problem that already has been mentioned. But one change that wasn't documented as far as I can tell is that the "[closed]", "[duplicate]", and "[migrated]" have been removed from question titles in the user activity page. A closed question is indistinguishable from any other on that page, which is different than pretty much every other page on the whole site.

The closed state must be visible in question lists on the user profile. Please fix this regression.

Comment: I guess you mean the questions sidebar tab of the activity page? Not that it matters since that small box on the main activity page shows only the first two words of each title and not if it's closed.

Comment: [related](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/372701/165773)

Answer (score 19):

Purely for illustrative purposes, and to lend further support. Below is a screenshot of a user's activity page and a list of questions asked by that author:

> [image]

It looks like all four questions are opened when in actual fact two have been closed as duplicates.

The information that a question is closed, for whatever reason, is missing.

Answer (score 5):

I agree, but in the meantime there's a decent workaround.

### As a moderator

Use the search box from the user's page (which is autofilled with `user:#####`) and add `deleted:all closed:1`. This gives you all the user's posts that have been closed, or you could just use `deleted:all is:q` if you wanted to see what questions are closed in the context of all their other questions.

### As a regular user

This can even be done on sites where you're not a moderator, except you can't see deleted posts unless you're looking at yourself and you have the ability to see deleted posts (awarded at 2k or [10k reputation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/moderator-tools), depending on the site).

So, when searching other users, use `user:##### closed:1` or `user:##### is:q`.

Use other [advanced search operators](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/searching) for many more options.

Answer (score 5):

This is now [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed).

See this screenshot of my question page:

[image: Duplicate status showing]

As you can see, it now shows "[duplicate]" next to my questions closed as duplicates.

Comment: Until we get official response, this fix might disappear in a puff of smoke, go away without notice. (So I won't build any hopes on it to stay.)

Comment: @ShadowWizardSaysNoMoreWar I doubt it, given that the part appended to the title isn't actually part of the post title; instead, the page has to query for the status. (See [this past bug report](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/207916/377214) where a page was incorrectly showing duplicate questions as "[closed]" instead of as "[duplicate]".)

Comment: I know, that's not my point. I mean that there's good chance a developer made a change that as side effect fixed the bug reported here, without ever meaning to do it, as they didn't see or worked on this bug report. So that change can be reverted any moment, or just invalidated by other change, as they have no idea it fixed something. (When bug is fixed, the developer fixing it usually says so, in this case, no response from any dev at any point)

Comment: @ShadowWizardSaysNoMoreWar A staff member [said](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/transcript/89?m=9031458#9031458) that it's OK to post answers saying "this has been completed". If it turns out to be invalid, staff can mark the request as such and post a comment here. It's tagged as under review and is as such on their radar.

Comment: All good, didn't mean you shouldn't have posted the answer. Just that it doesn't mean the fix is on purpose.

Comment: This was fixed network-wide for all close reasons a while back - we just failed to update the status here. Please let us know if it seems like anything got missed.