# Questions migrated to other sites incorrectly show as "closed" instead of "migrated" in search results

Tags: bug, search, migration

When a question is migrated to a different site, the copy on the original site (the migration stub) has "[migrated]" appended to the title. Here's an [example](https://superuser.com/questions/1722457/is-it-possible-to-create-a-gogle-image-search-url-for-a-specific-size-and-color?noredirect=1).

On the question page itself:

[image: "migrated" in title]

In the user's question list:

[image: "migrated" in title]

But in search results, "[closed]" is appended instead:

[image: "closed" in title]

What gets appended to the title should match in all cases. The search result should also show it as "[migrated]", not "[closed]".

This is especially applicable when searching for questions using the `migrated:1` search operator. That operator includes both questions migrated *to* and *from* the site. It used to be possible to tell the former from the latter, as the latter type of questions used to show as "[migrated]", but now it's not possible to do so, as those questions show up the same way as those in the former category that were later closed again. You also can't filter it out using `locked:1` as it includes rejected migrations to the site.

I brought up a [similar issue](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/207916/duplicate-questions-show-up-as-on-hold-and-closed-in-recently-deleted-questi) with my old account in 2013, and the issue there was that the page wasn't properly querying for the question status. I think it's the same root cause here.